# Making the subtraction posssible: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.datetime'

Tags: python

I'm Salech and I'm learning Python. Python is my really first programming language. It is my second day that I following the youtube video "from zero to hero". And my first problem that I can't solve is related to time and date.

The challenge:

- Ask a user to enter a deadline for their project
- Tell them how many days they have to complete the project
- For Extra Credit give them the answer as a combination of weeks & days

I made all of that, but then I thought to add an additional feature, which takes an input of time(hh:mm:ss) and prints this time minus the current time. Here's how I thought to do it:

```
import math
import datetime

currentDate = datetime.date.today()
currentTime = datetime.datetime.now()

deadLine = input('Hello, enter the deadline date for your project (mm/dd/yyyy)')
deadLineDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(deadLine, '%m/%d/%Y').date()

deadLineTime = input('insert time')
deadTime = datetime.datetime.strptime(deadLineTime, '%H:%M:%S').time()
print(deadTime)

daysLeft = deadLineDate - currentDate
print('%d days left' % daysLeft.days)


weeksLeft = math.floor(daysLeft.days/7)
newDaysLeft = daysLeft .days- 7*(math.floor(daysLeft.days/7))
print('You have %d weeks' % weeksLeft, ' and %d days left.' % newDaysLeft)

timeLeft = deadTime - currentTime 
print(timeLeft.hours)
```

With the input 02/04/2016 and 15:00 I get the following error:

```
Hello, enter the deadline date for your project (mm/dd/yyyy)02/04/2016
insert time15:00
15:00:00
5 days left
You have 0 weeks  and 5 days left.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/PYTHON/challenge04.py", line 31, in <module>
    timeLeft = deadTime - currentTime
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.datetime'
>>>
```

Edit: As jonatan said, testing the code without any input:

```
Hello, enter the deadline date for your project (mm/dd/yyyy)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/PYTHON/challenge04.py", line 14, in <module>
    deadLineDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(deadLine, '%m/%d/%Y').date()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/_strptime.py", line 507, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/_strptime.py", line 344, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data '' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y'
```

Thank You.

Comment: It would be much simpler to test your code if no input was required from the user!

Comment: @jonatan, thanks, good idea!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [`combine`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.combine) your `date` and your `time` into a `datetime`.

```
deadline = datetime.datetime.combine(deadLineDate, deadlineTime)
timeLeft = deadline - currentTime
```

The reason for the error is because it doesn't really make much sense to subtract a `date` from a `time`.  e.g. What is "4PM - Fri, Jan 29th?".

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
import math

currentDate=datetime.date.today()
currentTime=datetime.datetime.now()

UserInput1=input("What is the deadline for your project? mm/dd/yyyy  ")
deadLine=datetime.datetime.strptime(UserInput1, "%m/%d/%Y").date()

UserInput2=input("Please insert the time hh/mm/ss  ")
deadTime=datetime.datetime.strptime(UserInput2, "%H/%M/%S").time()


daysLeft= deadLine-currentDate
print("%d days left" % daysLeft.days)

weeksLeft=math.floor(daysLeft.days/7)
newDaysLeft=daysLeft.days-7*(math.floor(daysLeft.days/7))
print("You have %d weeks" % weeksLeft, "and %d days left."% newDaysLeft)

deadLine=datetime.datetime.combine(deadLine,deadTime)
timeLeft=deadLine-currentTime
print(timeLeft)
```

Comment: For your code to run, make sure it follows such a format.